# How to add a literal hash in a Spock unrolled method name?

Tags: groovy, spock

Spock's data-driven tests allow inserting data into the description, like this (from [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_method_unrolling)):

```
@Unroll
def "maximum of #a and #b is #c"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c

    where:
    a | b || c
    1 | 3 || 3
    7 | 4 || 7
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
maximum of 1 and 3 is 3   PASSED
maximum of 7 and 4 is 7   PASSED
```

But how can I insert a literal hash? e.g. When naming methods, I like to use the standard hash prefix:

```
@Unroll
def "Math#max(#a, #b) is #c"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c

    where:
    a | b || c
    1 | 3 || 3
    7 | 4 || 7
  }
}
```

But this results in:

```
Math#Error:max(1, 3) is 3   PASSED
Math#Error:max(7, 4) is 7   PASSED
```

I've tried escaping with a '\\' and a '#', neither seem to work.

Comment: You can't do that. Why not use `.`? `Math.max(a,b)` is more readable than `Math#max(a,b)`

Comment: The only way you can achieve such thing is to add `max` parameter to the data table with value `#max` for each data row. Then `@Unroll` would resolve `#max` to a `#max` literal. But this is very clumsy and verbose.

Comment: I could just use a '.', but my example is not the only case where I'd might want to print a literal '#'

Answer (score 0):

Unroll description is parsed using regular expression and there is no escape functionality.

But you can do one thing as a workaround - add another character after the `#` to don't match the regular expression like this:

```
def "Math#.max(#a, #b) is #c"() { ... }
```

And the message will be

> Math#.max(1, 3) is 3
>   Math#.max(7, 4) is 7

The regular expression used to parse the description is this: `#([a-zA-Z_$]([\w$.]|\(\))*)`. So you can use characters like `.!-` etc.

Comment: Presumably this could be patched to use negative look-behind to allow escaping with a double ##... something like `(?<!#)#([a-zA-Z_$]([\w$.]|\(\))*)`

Comment: Yes of course, then you can create feature request here https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues ;-)